# PEB (Process Environment Block) invalid DllBase address

Tags: c, winapi, portable-executable

I trying to get my own PEB and get my own module address. i wrote a simple code like this:

```
PLIST_ENTRY myModule = (PLIST_ENTRY)pebLdr->InMemoryOrderModuleList.Flink;

PLDR_DATA_TABLE_ENTRY myImageBase = (PLDR_DATA_TABLE_ENTRY)myModule;

PIMAGE_DOS_HEADER dosHeader = (PIMAGE_DOS_HEADER)myImageBase->DllBase;
```

But i dont see a proper PE header in `dosHeader`. This is what i see in the MSVC debugger in `dosHeader` variable : `e_magic=???,e_cblp=???` . Why cant i get my own header? I checked everything, im doing everything as documented, and i can see my exe name in a `pData->FullDllName`, everything seem to be correct, and the `DllBase` makes sense its not null or anything like `ffffff`. Is there any specific thing need to bee done, maybe address calculation?

Comment: Most likely `myImageBase` is not initialized correctly. Check `myImageBase->FullDllName`, does it contain valid module name? Also the is a possibility, that your SDK is too old, so `PLDR_DATA_TABLE_ENTRY` have been changed and you are reading using wrong offset.

Comment: @Ari0nhh i checked and i see that `myImageBase->FullDllName` has my valid exe name.

Comment: Why are you resorting to this low-level trickery, instead of using a higher-level call like [`NtQueryInformationProcess()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684280.aspx)? Setting `ProcessInformationClass` to `ProcessBasicInformation` "*retrieves a pointer to a PEB structure...*"

Comment: @RemyLebeau i read the book `windows internals by mark russinovich and david solomon` and i want to make some examples from there not only in windbg but in code

Comment: Like I said, in code, you can use `NtQueryInformationProcess()` to find the address of a process's PEB. Why don't you want to use that?

Comment: @RemyLebeau just for education purpose

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't do

```
PLDR_DATA_TABLE_ENTRY myImageBase = (PLDR_DATA_TABLE_ENTRY)myModule;
```

since `InMemoryOrderLinks` is not the first field in `LDR_DATA_TABLE_ENTRY`. Instead you should involve `CONTAINING_RECORD()` macro:

```
PLIST_ENTRY le = (PLIST_ENTRY)pebLdr->InMemoryOrderModuleList.Flink;
PLDR_DATA_TABLE_ENTRY mainModule = CONTAINING_RECORD(le, LDR_DATA_TABLE_ENTRY, InMemoryOrderLinks);
PIMAGE_DOS_HEADER dosHeader = (PIMAGE_DOS_HEADER)mainModule->DllBase;
```

To top it off: you can freely iterate through doubly-linked circular list of `LIST_ENTRY`'es and to obtain actual node data you should use `CONTAINING_RECORD()`. Note, that node which resides in `PEB_LDR_DATA` is dedicated and has no associated data. You should use it only as sign that you have walked through whole list.

Comment: But i get the first field here `PLIST_ENTRY myModule = (PLIST_ENTRY)pebLdr->InMemoryOrderModuleList.Flink;` `pebLdr` already points to `PEB_LDR_DATA`

Comment: And your `myModule` is just a pointer to `LIST_ENTRY` and nothing more. And this `LIST_ENTRY` is a `InMemoryOrderLinks `field in `LDR_DATA_TABLE_ENTRY`. You should adjust pointer to point to enclosing structure before using. A bit of docs: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa813708(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: can you show how to do this without macro for better understanding? So basically `pebLdr->InMemoryOrderModuleList.Flink;` points to `struct LDR_DATA_TABLE_ENTRY {
 LIST_ENTRY InLoadOrderLinks;
 LIST_ENTRY InMemoryOrderLinks;  <-- points here right?
 LIST_ENTRY InInitializationOrderLinks;
 .... }`

Comment: `typedef struct _PEB_LDR_DATA
{
     ULONG Length;
     UCHAR Initialized;
     PVOID SsHandle;
     LIST_ENTRY InLoadOrderModuleList;
     LIST_ENTRY InMemoryOrderModuleList;
     LIST_ENTRY InInitializationOrderModuleList;
     PVOID EntryInProgress;
} PEB_LDR_DATA, *PPEB_LDR_DATA;` so with this better documented version i see, if i'd choosen to iterate using `InLoadOrderModuleList` i could do what i'v done in op-post right? Because i will get the pointer to the first field right?

Comment: Yes, if you choose `InLoadOrderModuleList` you can use your approach, because `InLoadOrderLinks` placed at the same memory location as whole `LDR_DATA_TABLE_ENTRY`.  But I strongly recommend using of macro anyway since it is more convenient and less fragile way to iterate through such lists. Moreover it is available at win SDK.

Comment: `CONTAINING_RECORD()` just evaluates byte offset of specified field in enclosing structure and then subtracts this offset from applied pointer to get pointer to structure. And if you really want - you can do it by yourself.

Comment: E.g. wine uses next implementation http://source.winehq.org/git/wine.git/blob/refs/tags/wine-1.9.14:/include/winnt.h#l756.