# Unhandled exception thrown: read access violation error when accessing dos header of DLL

Tags: c++, winapi, process

I am trying to access the dos header of a DLL PE file. I am getting the address of the IMAGE_DOS_HEADER from the PEB of my process. I am getting the address by accessing the PEB, then accessing the LDR and then scanning the InMemoryOrderModuleList until I find the DLL I want to access (on this case the kernel32.DLL), and use the dllbase to convert it to IMAGE_DOS_HEADER. After getting the DLL base I am getting the following error :

```
Unhandled exception thrown: read access violation
```

my code:

```cpp
HMODULE hNtDll = LoadLibraryA("ntdll.dll");
typedef NTSTATUS(NTAPI* pfNtQueryInformationProcess)(HANDLE ProcessHandle, PROCESSINFOCLASS ProcessInformationClass, PVOID ProcessInformation, ULONG ProcessInformationLength, PULONG ReturnLength);
pfNtQueryInformationProcess ntQueryInformationProcess = (pfNtQueryInformationProcess)GetProcAddress(hNtDll, "NtQueryInformationProcess");
PROCESS_BASIC_INFORMATION pBasicInfo;
NTSTATUS status = ntQueryInformationProcess(hProcess, ProcessBasicInformation, &pBasicInfo, sizeof(pBasicInfo), 0);
PPEB peb = pBasicInfo.PebBaseAddress;
PPEB_LDR_DATA ldrData = (PPEB_LDR_DATA)peb->Ldr;
PLIST_ENTRY firstitem_InMemoryOrderModuleList = &ldrData->InMemoryOrderModuleList;
PLIST_ENTRY currentitem_InMemoryOrderModuleList = firstitem_InMemoryOrderModuleList->Flink;
while (true) {
    LDR_DATA_TABLE_ENTRY inMemoryOrderModuleListItem = *(PLDR_DATA_TABLE_ENTRY)currentitem_InMemoryOrderModuleList;
    if (inMemoryOrderModuleListItem.FullDllName.Buffer == NULL) {
        break;
    }
    wcout << inMemoryOrderModuleListItem.FullDllName.Buffer << endl;
    wcout << inMemoryOrderModuleListItem.DllBase << endl;
    PIMAGE_DOS_HEADER dosHeader = (PIMAGE_DOS_HEADER)inMemoryOrderModuleListItem.DllBase;
    if (!wcscmp(inMemoryOrderModuleListItem.FullDllName.Buffer, L"KERNEL32.DLL")) {
        PIMAGE_DOS_HEADER dosHeader = (PIMAGE_DOS_HEADER)(inMemoryOrderModuleListItem.DllBase);
        cout << "-------------------------" << endl;
        PIMAGE_NT_HEADERS ntHeader = (PIMAGE_NT_HEADERS)((DWORD_PTR)dosHeader + dosHeader->e_lfanew); // error on this line because trying to access the dosHeader
    }
    currentitem_InMemoryOrderModuleList = currentitem_InMemoryOrderModuleList->Flink;
}
```

Comment: Actually, getting a pointer to kernel32.dll's DOS header can be done simply by casting the result of GetModuleHandle("kernel32.dll") to a pointer.

Comment: Yes I know, I am using this method for a reason. I am trying to use a function without import it.

Comment: I am not sure I understand what you mean by `without importing it` - do you mean without explicitly loading the dll?

Comment: @GiladDiCastro You can't access a DLL's functions without the DLL being loaded into memory first. And once it has been loaded via `LoadLibrary/Ex()`, `GetModuleHandle()` can find it and return its base address, so you don't need to resort to using the PEB directly to find it manually, eg: `HMODULE hMod = GetModuleHandle("kernel32.dll"); PIMAGE_DOS_HEADER dosHeader = reinterpret_cast<PIMAGE_DOS_HEADER>(hMod); PIMAGE_NT_HEADERS ntHeader = reinterpret_cast<PIMAGE_NT_HEADERS>((reinterpret_cast<DWORD_PTR>(dosHeader) + dosHeader->e_lfanew)); ...`

Comment: @RemyLebeau I know, this is why my example is for kernel32.dll

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> And your `currentitem_InMemoryOrderModuleList` is just a pointer to
>   `LIST_ENTRY`. And this `LIST_ENTRY` is a `InMemoryOrderLinks` field in
>   `LDR_DATA_TABLE_ENTRY`. You can adjust pointer to point to enclosing
>   structure before using.

Refer to "[PEB (Process Environment Block) invalid DllBase address](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38319593/peb-process-environment-block-invalid-dllbase-address)", "[CONTAINING_RECORD](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/kernel/mm-bad-pointer#containing_record)" (Which returns the base address of an instance of a structure given the type of the structure and the address of a field within the containing structure.).

The following code works for me. You can have a try:

```
while (true) {
    LDR_DATA_TABLE_ENTRY inMemoryOrderModuleListItem = *(CONTAINING_RECORD(currentitem_InMemoryOrderModuleList, LDR_DATA_TABLE_ENTRY, InMemoryOrderLinks));
    if (inMemoryOrderModuleListItem.FullDllName.Buffer == NULL) {
        break;
    }
    std::wcout << inMemoryOrderModuleListItem.FullDllName.Buffer << endl;
    std::wcout << inMemoryOrderModuleListItem.DllBase << endl;
    PIMAGE_DOS_HEADER dosHeader = (PIMAGE_DOS_HEADER)inMemoryOrderModuleListItem.DllBase;
    if (!wcscmp(inMemoryOrderModuleListItem.FullDllName.Buffer, L"C:\\WINDOWS\\System32\\KERNEL32.DLL")) {
        PIMAGE_DOS_HEADER dosHeader = (PIMAGE_DOS_HEADER)(inMemoryOrderModuleListItem.DllBase);
        cout << "-------------------------" << endl;
        PIMAGE_NT_HEADERS ntHeader = (PIMAGE_NT_HEADERS)((DWORD_PTR)dosHeader + dosHeader->e_lfanew); // error on this line because trying to access the dosHeader
    }
    currentitem_InMemoryOrderModuleList = currentitem_InMemoryOrderModuleList->Flink;
}
```